# Should Admin and User records be stored in the same table for a website with separated frontend and backend?

Tags: database-design, admin, record

I have 2 separated section: frontend & backend with their login pages. Frontend is for user to register and do something with their stuffs. Backend is for administrator to manage resources. Someone told me that it is more convenient if we want to promote a normal user to admin role if I use 1 table. However, for example, I want to create a new admin, I have to sequentially fill in all the related details that a normal user is required to register. It is such a waste of time.

Do you think it is better to store both admin & user records in one table in general case and also in my case?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can store both of them in same table and for admin user add one column like isAdmin of "Y" "N" to avoid filling all fields used for normal user.